# Dynamic Xml (I think)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

EDIT:  Thank you all for your help. I edited my Database class to contain the following

```
    final EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  // First Name
    final EditText middleName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);  // Middle Name
    final EditText birthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);  // Birth Date

    final String firstname = firstName.getText().toString();  // First Name
    final String middlename = middleName.getText().toString();  // Middle Name
    final String birthdate = birthDate.getText().toString();  // Birth Date

    TextView firstNameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    TextView middleNameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.middlename);
    TextView birthDateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birthdate);

    firstNameText.setText(firstname);
    middleNameText.setText(middlename);
    birthDateText.setText(birthdate);
```

and my database.xml now shows

```
 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:background="#aa0000"            
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:id="@+id/firstname"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#00aa00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:id="@+id/middlename"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#0000aa"          
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:id="@+id/birthdate"/>
    </TableRow>
```

but when I run the emulator and I try to access that screen (by clicking a button from the previous screen) the application crashes? I set up the button correctly using the OnClickListener so I'm fairly sure the button is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble understanding the interface here's an example you can cut and paste.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="First Name: "
    android:id="@+id/firstLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dip"
    />
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/firstEdit" 
    android:text="John"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Middle Name: "
    android:id="@+id/middleLabel"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dip"/>
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/middleEdit" 
    android:text="Phillip"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstEdit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/middleLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Last Name: "
    android:id="@+id/lastLabel"
    android:layout_below="@id/middleLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dip"
    />
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/lastEdit" 
    android:text="Doe"
    android:layout_below="@id/middleEdit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Birthdate: "
    android:id="@+id/birthLabel"
    android:layout_below="@id/lastLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dip"
    />
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/birthEdit" 
    android:text="08/09/1977"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastLabel"
    android:layout_below="@id/lastEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/birthEdit">
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:background="#aa0000"            
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:text="something"
        android:id="@+id/firstTable"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#00aa00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:text="something1"
        android:id="@+id/middleTable"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#0000aa"          
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:text="something2"
        android:id="@+id/birthTable"/>
    </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

DatabaseExample.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatabaseExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Setup edit fields
        EditText firstEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstEdit);
        EditText middleEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.middleEdit);
        EditText lastEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastEdit);
        EditText birthEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.birthEdit);


        //Get the text and store in variables
        String firstName = firstEdit.getText().toString();
        String middleName = middleEdit.getText().toString();
        String lastName = lastEdit.getText().toString();
        String birthDate = birthEdit.getText().toString();

        //setup the text fields
        TextView firstTable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstTable);
        TextView middleTable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.middleTable);
        TextView birthTable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birthTable);

        //change the text fields
        firstTable.setText(firstName);
        middleTable.setText(middleName);
        birthTable.setText(birthDate);


    }
}
```

Once again this would be just the interface for inputting and displaying data.  Instead of storing the data in String variables you would use SQLite, SharedPreferences, or write to a file on the SDCard.

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows

```
final EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
TextView firstNameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstname); 
firstNameTxt.setText(firstName);
```

Comment: This is what you want to dynamically change a TextView. You don't have to give it an `android:text` value at all if you don't want, as long as it's set later.

Comment: Thanks. I did this but now my app in the emulator is getting an error and closing itself. I edited what my new code is in my original question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store values from the user in the strings.xml file. You must have a data store such as [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [SQLite.](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is another link for help on data storage with Android.